# Using Redis in Heroku for a React and Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I have a Rails API deployed onto heroku, which serves to a React.js Static page. There both deployed on heroku, and they comunicate through an API link. My struggle is comming when using Redis and Sidekiq.

On my Rails API I got the RedisToGo link Configured with no issues, but when I go to my React app and try to send an email invite I get this message `Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)`.
I thought if I have it configured on my backend then it would work to my react static page app.

**Sidekiq.yml**

```
---
:verbose: false
:concurrency: 3
staging:
  :concurrency: 1
production:
  :concurrency: 5
:queues:
  - [mailers,2]
  - slack_notifications
  - mixpanel
  - invoices
  - default
  - rollbar
```

**Redis.rb**

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri)
```

**sidekiq.rb**

```
Sidekiq::Extensions.enable_delay!

unless Rails.env == 'development' || Rails.env == 'test'
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = {
      url: Rails.application.credentials.redis_url,
      password: Rails.application.credentials.redis_password
    }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = {
      url: Rails.application.credentials.redis_url,
      password: Rails.application.credentials.redis_password
    }
  end
end

# Turn off backtrace if at all memory issues are popping up as
# backtrace occupies to much memory on redis
# number of lines of backtrace and number of re-tries
Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { backtrace: false, retry: 3 }

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  # runs after your app has finished initializing
  # but before any jobs are dispatched.
  config.on(:startup) do
    puts 'Sidekiq is starting...'
    # make_some_singleton
  end
  config.on(:quiet) do
    puts 'Got USR1, stopping further job processing...'
  end
  config.on(:shutdown) do
    puts 'Got TERM, shutting down process...'
    # stop_the_world
  end
end
```

So my question is the next one:
If I have already configured a REDISTOGO_LINK on my rails app, do I need the same on my react config vars?

Whats the best way to configure sidekiq and Redis on a Rails API using react as a front-end in heroku? I haven't seen something that covers this on the internet.

I would  appreciate your help! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL` to tell Sidekiq to use REDISTOGO_URL to connect to Redis.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#using-an-env-variable

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks for your kind response. So if I have already on my rails app in heroku the redis_provider. I wont need it on my react static app right?

Comment: I assume you are correct. Sidekiq works with Rails on the backend.